# GIT Issue where git clone asks for password

Tags: git, gitolite

I have generated ssh key and PUB key placed in keydir of the gitoliteèadmin repo.
When I clone the Repo to my local it asks for password.
Already existing users are able to clone the Repo.

`Authorised_keys` file is not getting updated when changes done in `keydir`.
As push at `keydir` shows everything up to date.

How to make `authorised_keys` (under `~git/.ssh`) file to update automatically as earlier?
It should trigger automatically when we update PUB key under keydir.

Answer (score 2):

`keydir` means you are using **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)**.

More specifically, you have cloned [the `gitolite_admin` repo](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#the-special-gitolite-admin-repo), and try to declare a new user.

> As push at keydir shows everything up to date

Check your git status: you need to add *and* commit your changes (ie your new public key file in the keydir folder) before trying to push.

As [baron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262830/baron) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825132/git-issue-where-git-clone-asks-for-password/39825891#comment72023868_39825891), ssh expects to validate a public key in ~/.ssh/authori**z**ed_keys, not authori**s**ed_keys.
So if it is not a typo in the question, fix the file name.

Comment: Hi Vonc, yes we are using gitolite.Yes, am trying to add new user with new pub key ; have done git add . & commit and the push to remote. Everything works fine. But, the pubkey is not updating under authorused_keys file. If we manually copy the pubkey(after adding it under key dir with git add, commit & push) its works fine without asking password. So, all we need is to automatically it should trigger the pub key when we add new user under keydir.. Before it waas fine from last 15 days its not working.

Comment: @Kumar Exactly, so check your git status: did you manage to clone the gitolite_admin repo?

Comment: @Kumar On the server side, in  `$HOME/repositories/gitolite-admin.git`, does a `git log` shows your new commit?

Comment: yes, git status shows the the things we are done...It show the following status On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
But, changes are done in keydir but not reflecting @ authorised_keys

Comment: git stauts on your side?, or directly on the gitolite server, in `$HOME/repositories/gitolite-admin.git`?

Comment: under gitolite-admin.git dir structure is branches ( COMMIT_EDITMSG  config  description  gl-conf  HEAD  hooks  index  info  logs  objects  refs) under logs we have HEAD &refs

Comment: gitolite server side

Comment: /home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git/logs/refs

Comment: in git status it shows.. this content deleted.. is this the cause?
 deleted:    ../conf/.gitolite.conf.swp

Comment: Did you try to add the key directly on the server in home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git? Or did you clone that repo on your desktop, add the key there, commit and push?

Comment: actually under gitolite-admin we have keydir & conf.. Under keydir we add PUB key with user name. Then user use to clone that repo on desktop. But , now when we add PUB key for new user keydir gets updated but the authorised_key file under .ssh folder is not getting the new user pubkey in that and it asks for password to clone on desktop. So, as of urgency with user i have updated the new PUB key in key dir with add, commit & push and then copied the PUB key under aouthorised_key file manually it works fine. But, issu is why its not getting updated/triggered when we update @ keydir

Comment: This is the server path where we add key dir.. /home/gitadmin/gitolite-admin/keydir...

Comment: @Kumar if you see the right commit on the server side, try on the server to type `gitolite setup` and see if the authorized_keys file is updated then.

Comment: under this path it should get updated when keydir updates..
/home/git/.ssh/authorised_keys

Comment: where i have to type gitolite setup.. could you please brief.@ which location i have to do this

Comment: @Kumar Sure: fix your PATH, and add  ~/gitolite/bin (or wherever you have installed gitolite on the server)

Comment: I have an issue regarding clearcase
unable to open graphical lsvtree -g shows the following error.
xclearcase : warning: could not load font 'GB2312.1980-0'

Comment: kindly let me know how to resolve?
 xclearcase : warning: could not load font 'KSC5601.1987-0'
 xclearcase : warning: could not load font 'JISX0208.1983-0

Comment: @Kumar, rename your authori**s**ed_keys to authori**z**ed_keys and you should be just fine :)

Comment: @baron True. I assumed it was a type, but just in case, I have referenced your comment in the answer for more visibility.